# How do I delete records in the recycle bin?

Tags: apex, soql, dml, recycle-bin

I understand that when I perform a `Database.delete()` operation, records will end up in my org's recycle bin. And their presence in the recycle bin is reflected by the `IsDeleted` field on the object.

But if those records are (for example) scrapes of a web page, they are of little interest to users and I don't want them kicking around in the org. Currently the only way I can see to 'hide' them would be to misuse a Protected (List) Custom Setting object.

From Apex, how can I delete a record and skip this, so it doesn't clutter a user's recycle bin?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Database.emptyRecycleBin(obj)` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_emptyRecycleBin_2) or the [other variants in the Database class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm) such as [`Database.emptyRecycleBin(listOfSObjects)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_emptyRecycleBin_3)

For example, to permanently delete a contact with Id of '003i000000O4xYZ' in the recycle bin:

```
Contact c = new Contact(Id = '003i000000O4XyZ');
Database.emptyRecycleBin(c);
```

Comment: Just nipped me to the post on this one Peter! ;-) Also note that there is a couple of other variants of this method. One which takes a list of Id's as well.

Comment: Good point.  Updated the answer. Being on xmas vacation I don't have _my actual work_ to get in the way of important things like tending to the SFSE. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Peter Knolle, it was quite useful. I think the links in the answer are not working any more, though, I am receiving a 404 Not Found error. I guess it was referencing Apex Developer's Guide, so it was quite easy to find the related entry there.

Comment: @JesusArcasFinancialForce - Thanks.  I updated the answer with fixed links.

Comment: And I updated the links again. Dammit, Salesforce, stop breaking the internet.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to hard delete using DataBase.emptyRecycleBin method in the Batch class. Create a sample Batch class as mentioned below and use DataBase.emptyRecycleBin method in the Batch class.

```
global class BatchDeletion implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable{   
    global BatchDeletion(){}

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id from Account where Name='Test Account12']);
    } 

    //Execute method for the Schedulable interface
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){   
        //execute the batch
        BatchDeletion deleteCS = new BatchDeletion();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(deleteCS);
    }

    //Execute method for the batchable interface
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<sObject> scope){     
        delete scope;   
        DataBase.emptyRecycleBin(scope); 
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

Note: 1.   The DML operation  datatbase.emptyRecycleBin is limited to 200 items, it is a known issue and currently no workaround is possible for this.
 http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000STLXAA4

Comment: Thanks for this example.  Never dawned on me that you could combine the schedulable and batchable interfaces in one class like you have done here.  Also, thanks for the emptyRecycleBin example.  Upvoted.