# Empty Your Recycle Bin Performance

Tags: performance, recycle-bin, cleanup

`Empty Your Recycle Bin` or `Empty Your Organization's Recycle Bin` works very slow. Is there some faster way to empty the salesforce recycle bin.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Apex `Database.emptyRecycleBin(sObject[])`. If you combine that with a batch process you should get reasonable throughput.

There is an example of doing this via a batch in the question [How do I delete records in the recycle bin?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/41478/102)

Comment: Is there a variant of this method using which we can use to delete all the 'Accounts' in single call without having to provide Id of record to be deleted? I have 100K+ records to be deleted.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava Nope. However, if you wait about 24 hours, salesforce should truncate the list down to about 5000 records per user.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava As sfdxfox mentioned, you could wait until Salesforce automatically starts deleting records from the bin. The 200 records per batch execution is a limitation of the emptyRecycleBin method. Or at lease the SOAP version. It looks like the [Apex version will do 10,000 per call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_emptyRecycleBin).

Comment: Although Apex version can do 10K per call but it still requires list of ids. Can I not do this only on object name instead of using ids. (Makes sense not to use id when i want to delete entire dataset)
What is the fastest way to delete 100K records of same object from recycle bin?