# How to empty the recycle bin via REST API

Tags: rest-api

I'm looking for a way to empty either all object or specific objects in the recycle bin.

I found a way with APEX ([How do I delete records in the recycle bin?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22875/how-do-i-delete-records-in-the-recycle-bin/41478#41478)) and the SOAP API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_emptyrecyclebin.htm) but I was wondering if this is also possible via the REST API?

Can anybody support me here?

Thanks in advance
Karin

Answer (score 2):

A brief look through the REST API docs suggests that there is not a resource provided to do this out of the box.

...but since we can make custom REST resources in Apex by using the `@RestResource` annotation, and you can empty the recycle bin via Apex, it is possible for you to add this functionality to the REST API *for your org*.

If you're using the batch class approach, you'd need to have your `@RestResource` class handle the job of starting the execution of the batch class (I suppose it *might* be possible to add this annotation to an additional method in your batch class, but I think mixing responsibilities like that would leave a bad taste in my mouth).